# Matlab parfor in different script file "exist" error

Tags: matlab, parfor

My code runs ok if all parfor code is in the same script file, but since the code is huge and I want to select parallel or serial mode execution, I separated it in a different script file, as fallow:

```
if (useParFor)
   myParforCode.m
else
   serialCode.m
end
```

The problem is that Matlab gives me this error:
"Using exist to check for a variable in the transparent workspace is
not supported."
But if I copy all the code in myParforCode.m and put it after the if statement instead of calling the script, the code runs. I thought I could divide my code in scripts without problems, but it seams it not like that.

What are the limitations here, what I'm doing wrong?

My code is huge but I'll try to create a running code sample and add it here.

Comment: *I'll try to create a running code sample and add it here.* <- Do this before asking. However, do you have a call for the fucntion `exists` inside myParfprCode?

Comment: @AnderBiguri No, there is no call to exists. Also, I asked before the sample because some one could already know what is the problem.